# How to add images to existing PDF file in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a PDF of a purchase contract and I need to add an image of my debit card to it. So far, I've opened the image of my card in a separate file and used the magnetic lasso tool to select it. In another window, I have my PDF opened. I've tried using the "Paste Into" command to paste the image into an rectangular area I've selected, but two things happen--

1. The image of my card is automatically greyscaled.
2. I cannot transform the image at all. I would like to shrink it so it fits the dimensions of the layer mask.

I've noticed that the paste into command is not creating any new layers. Could this be because I'm opening a PDF? Should I be converting the PDF to a different format? If so, how?

Thanks all.

Photoshop CC 2014 (all updates installed)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular paste. That creates a separate layer for the pasted object, and you can use the regular tools to move, size, and rotate it. You don't need to 'mark' or otherwise define a destination rectangle. This *can* be useful, but only for very specific operations. As you found out, yours is not one of them, as you want to paste and then manipulate the pasted object.

> .. The image of my card is automatically greyscaled.

The pasted part automatically gets converted to the *destination* color space. You don't mention it, but I am guessing your PDF is opened in grayscale. If you want to paste in a color image, first convert the destination image to an appropriate color space such as RGB.

Note that (contrary to what you seem to think, based on your title) you cannot "add" an image to an existing PDF with Photoshop (with a *single exception*: if that PDF was originally created with Photoshop). Photoshop cannot 'edit' PDFs; when 'opening', you are actually converting the entire PDF to a large bitmap image. All original vector and text information will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Illustrator can open PDF files in an editable way. If you open the PDF in Illustrator, you can then copy/paste the image from photoshop. Then save as a PDF again.